# Migrating from one mail server to another.how?

Tags: email, web-hosting, email-server

So untill recently I have been using own email hosting using smartermail. Now I am tryin to migrate a bunch of my clients to shared hosting. (in my case rackspace cloud hosting).

The only problem is getting the clients emails migrated to rackspaces email hosting.

Anyone know the procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the mailboxes on the new system.

Setup the clients to look at the new mailboxes.

Change the DNS to point the MX records to the new host.

Check both services for at least a week as DNS replicates and people that don't update DNS very often still send to the old system.

When we moved, it took about a week or two for mail to stop arriving at the old server.

Comment: You might also look into setting up mail forwarding from the old accounts to the new, if possible, to ease the transition.

Comment: Good point.  I'm not that nice.  Made the users do some work.  We only have about 80 or so, so it wasn't that bad.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have all the user accounts provisioned on the new service, check out [imapsync](http://freshmeat.net/projects/imapsync/) for copying the mail from the old accounts to the new accounts. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Rackspace Email, or hosting your own Email server on Rackspace's servers.

If you're using Rackspace Email, Rackspace has introduced an automated migration tool last November that can migrate email via IMAP or POP3, from both regular IMAP/POP servers or Exchange servers. It worked very well when I used it.

The Migration App can be accessed from within the Rackspace Apps Control Panel, under Domains -> Tools -> Migrations.